# jQuery select an image and then crop it

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

**How do I crop my selected picture?**

I've written web page that gives the user a choice to replace their current picture with a picture inside a carousel.

```
<div class="rcrop-wrapper">
    <img id="ZoomAvatarPicture" src="Pictures/PhotoAlbum/203.jpg" height="200" />
</div>

<div class="owl-carousel-v4 margin-bottom-40">
    <div class="owl-slider-v4">
        <div class="item"> 
            <img src="Pictures/PhotoAlbum/90.jpg"  onclick="$('#ZoomAvatarPicture').attr('src','Pictures/PhotoAlbum/90.jpg"/>
        </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="Pictures/PhotoAlbum/22.jpg" onclick="$('#ZoomAvatarPicture').attr('src','Pictures/PhotoAlbum/22.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="Pictures/PhotoAlbum/21.jpg" onclick="$('#ZoomAvatarPicture').attr('src','Pictures/PhotoAlbum/21.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the images in the carousel the ZoomAvatarPicture is replaced, as I expect it. I want to crop the newly selected ZoomAvatarPicture image.  I've tried 3rd party cropping software (e.g. jQuery rcrop and imgAreaSelect) but their cropped images are of the original image, 203.jpg)

This is the code I added for rcrop:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop({
        full: true,
        preserveAspectRatio: true,
        minSize: [50, 50],
        inputsPrefix: '',
        grid: false,
    });

    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').on('rcrop-changed', function e() {
        var srcResized = $(this).rcrop('getDataURL', 50, 50);
        $('#cropped-resized').append('<img src="' + srcResized + '">');
    })
});
```

And then I had a div to hold the cropped image

```
<div id="cropped-resized">
    <h3>Images resized (50x50)</h3>
</div>
```

Since I got the same results for rcrop and imageSelect it leads me to believe that the problem isn't in the software but in my understanding of what can be done in jQuery.

Also, the demo page for rcrop is here: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Mobile-friendly-Image-Cropper-With-jQuery-rcrop/

I've added this code

```
function rcrop_Avatar() 
{

        var srcResized = $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop('getDataURL', 50, 50);
        $('#cropped-resized').append('<img src="' + srcResized + '">');
        alert('src = ' + $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').attr('src') );
}

function resetListener()
{
    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').off(onclick, 'rcrop-changed', rcrop_Avatar);
    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop({
        preserveAspectRatio: true,
        minSize: [100, 100],
        inputs: true,
        inputsPrefix: '',
        preview: {
            display: true,
            size: [200, 200],
            wrapper: '#custom-preview-wrapper'
        }
    });
    rcrop_Avatar();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    App.init();
    App.initScrollBar();
    Datepicker.initDatepicker();
    OwlCarousel.initOwlCarousel();
    CirclesMaster.initCirclesMaster1();
    StyleSwitcher.initStyleSwitcher();
    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop({
        preserveAspectRatio: true,
        minSize: [100, 100],
        inputs: true,
        inputsPrefix: '',
        preview: {
            display: true,
            size: [200, 200],
            wrapper: '#custom-preview-wrapper'
        }
    });
    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').on('rcrop-changed', rcrop_Avatar);
});
```

and modified the HTML to this:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="Pictures/PhotoAlbum/Work/90.jpg"  onclick="$('#CurrentAvatarPicture').attr('src','Pictures/PhotoAlbum/Work/90.jpg');resetListener();"/>
</div>
```

I'm still getting the same results. (i.e. the cropped image is the original image, not the newly selected one).

The entire process is in a bootstrap modal. I'm starting to think I should forgo this route and put everything into a tabbed series of iframes.

Comment: Where are you defining `PictureID`? What does the console shows when you try to eval from there?

Comment: @LordNeo I removed PictureID. It was a field in a table in my database. I re-wrote the problem.

Comment: please post the code you're trying to use (either with rcrop or imgAreaSelect) so i can help you fix it.

Comment: @LordNeo  I've updated the original posting to include how I used rcrop.

Comment: ok, thing is, you're calling the rcrop on the original element and when the crop area is being changed (the screen is resized). You should also call rcrop when the src of the image changes, like adding it into your onclick call.

Comment: @LordNeo Thanks again for your input. I tried your suggestions and modified the original posting. I didn't see any change.

Comment: OK, the onclick event had mismatched  `"`, i'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, rcrop doesn't like to change properties or subject on the fly, and the destroy method is pretty messy, as it sometimes deletes the original object or leaves the preview display behind.

So, to avoid that, I changed a bit the behaviour to delete the remains and then recreate the image and attach it to the rcrop again.

Due to the size limit of the answers and not being able to upload the js and css of rcrop, i made this Codepen: http://codepen.io/LordNeo/pen/XpxVVv

Here is the relevant parts so you can check for modifications, for working example see the above CodePen.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop({
        full: true,
        minSize : [50,50],
        preserveAspectRatio : true,
        inputsPrefix: '',
        grid: false,
        preview : {
          display: true,
          size : [100,100],
        }
    });
});

function changeImage(imgsrc) {
   $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop("destroy");
   $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').remove();
   $('.rcrop-preview-wrapper').remove();
   $('.rcrop-wrapper').prepend('<img id="ZoomAvatarPicture" src="'+imgsrc+'" height="200" />');
   $('#ZoomAvatarPicture').rcrop({
     full: true,
     minSize : [50,50],
     preserveAspectRatio : true,
     inputsPrefix: '',
     grid: false,
     preview : {
       display: true,
       size : [100,100],
     }
   });
}
```

```html
<div class="rcrop-wrapper">
    <img id="ZoomAvatarPicture" src="http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG1" height="200" />
</div>

<div class="owl-carousel-v4 margin-bottom-40">
    <div class="owl-slider-v4">
        <div class="item"> 
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG2"  onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG2')"/>
        </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG3" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG3')"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG4" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/400x100/E8117F/FFFFFF?text=IMG4')"/>
    </div>
</div>
```